# How to Extract a result from a SqlReader Returned from OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader

Tags: ms-access, f#, sqldatareader, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I have looked at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543363/use-sqldatareader-in-f#12546177) and similar articles. I have a much simpler problem, which is to get the result of a `select count(*)`.

I am keeping track of file names and dates, by storing them in an MS Access database. I can find whether or not I've already added a file name and date to the database by performing a `select count(*)` on the database like this:

```
let query = "select count(*) from ReportProcessedStatus 
                             where ReportDate = #" + report_date + "#
                             and ReportFileName = '" + fn + "'"
```

My `cmd.ExecuteReader ()` succeeds, but I am having trouble figuring out how to get the count's value out of the reader.

```
let reg_fnam_template = "arrgster*"

let ADOCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=.\Munis_To_InvoiceCloud.mdb")
    ADOCon.Open ()    

let dir_list = Directory.GetFiles(spool_dir, reg_fnam_template)

for fn in dir_list do
printfn "Working on Munis Extract File: %A " (Path.GetFileName(fn))
let query = "select count(*) from ReportProcessedStatus where ReportDate = #" + report_date + "# and ReportFileName = '" + fn + "'"
    use cmd = new OleDbCommand(query , ADOCon)
    let sql_reader = cmd.ExecuteReader ()
    let row_read_OK = sql_reader.Read ()
```

All this code works, and the row_read_OK is true after executing.

Comment: You might want to look into [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ExecuteReader`