# nested runtime coercion for a Nullable double

Tags: f#, type-conversion, type-coercion

Let's say I have a value defined as a sort of commission formula

```
let address_commission = 1.0 // minimal simplified example
```

and I want to apply the above said commission to an amount I'm reading from the DB (the code is from a window WCF service I have in production)

```
let address_commission = 1.0 // minimal simplified example
new Model.ClaimModel( 
  //RequestRow = i, recounting
  Code = (row.["claim_code"] :?> string), 
  EvtDate = (row.["event_date"] :?> DateTime),
  // skipping lines...
  Amount = (row.["amount"] :?> double) * address_commission,
```

now I see that the amount line compiles fine, but I also need to include the same commission in the following

```
PrevAmount = (if row.IsNull("prev_amount")  then Nullable()  else  (row.["prev_amount"] :?> Nullable<double>)),
```

which is wrong since `The type 'float' does not match the type 'obj'`

Therefore I've tried also

```
PrevAmount = (if row.IsNull("prev_amount")  then Nullable()  else  (((row.["prev_amount"] :?> double) * address_commission) :?> Nullable<double>)),
```

but it also fails with `The type 'double' does not have any proper subtypes and cannot be used as the source of a type test or runtime coercion.`

What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: I think `:?> double` is wrong and you want `:? double` which should fix the error you have printed

Comment: @JohnPalmer I'm unsure but it doesn't seem to be the problem... actually now I've found a different solution by wrapping that part into a `Nullable(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:?>` is a dynamic cast and it's only checked at run-time so better try to avoid it. If you are accessing databases it helps to open the `open FSharp.Linq.NullableOperators` [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/nullable-operators). (The link is gone for me but it's somewhere on docs or msdn). Then you can use `?*?` and similar operators. For example:

```
let x = System.Nullable<float> 4.
let y = x ?* 3.0
//val y : System.Nullable<float> = 12.0
```

You can have `?` on either or both sides.

You will get back a Nullable float which you can coerce to an option with 
`Option.ofNullable(y)` or to a double `float y`.

Comment: Aside from `null`, the fundamental *dynamic* cast is *still* needed when I read from DB, since it has to cast from `obj` to `double` ... or am I  missing something else in your answer?

Comment: And back to `Nullable`,  I will have to convert from `DBNull` anyway, unless I leverage some [functional wrapper](http://bugsquash.blogspot.it/2010/10/functional-wrapper-over-adonet.html) for DB data access

Comment: Well, it would be best if you could use one of the type providers, like [Sqlpovider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/), which would pull the correct type for you. If you get back an `obj` then yes, you'll need to maybe unbox/cast. I try to avoid ADO.net (where DBNull comes from I assume), but it seems `FSSql` would do some of t he wrapping. Isn't there some some WCF/WSDL F# type provider?

Comment: or can you at least do a static cast with `:>`?

Comment: I found also this nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12543533/6996876) pointing to an interesting msdn [helper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh304373(v=vs.100).aspx#asd). Thank you for your time!

Comment: Ah, yes, the dynamic operator. You're most welcome. There's an F# Slack feel free to drop by, by [joining FSSF](http://foundation.fsharp.org/join).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use only one type coercion and wrap it within a `Nullable(...)`

```
PrevAmount = (if row.IsNull("prev_amount")  then Nullable()  else  Nullable((row.["prev_amount"]  :?> double) * address_commission)),
```

It compiles and looks ok to me, but I'm still open to different answers if they are more correct than mine